# How to get URL from the XPATH?

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, html-agility-pack

I've tried to check other answers on this site, but none of them worked for me. I have following HTML code:

```
<h3 class="x-large lheight20 margintop5">
  <a href="http://someUrl.com" class="marginright5 link linkWithHash detailsLink"><strong>some textstring</strong></a>
</h3>
```

I am trying to get **#** from this document with following code:

```
string adUrl = Doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id=\"offers_table\"]/tbody/tr["+i+ "]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/h3/a/@href").InnerText;
```

I've also tried to do that without `@href`. Also tried with `a[contains(@href, 'searchString')]`. But all of these lines gave me just the name of the link - **some textstring**

Comment: InnerText? Why are you trying to use it instead of getting attribute (which is what `href` is? Like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750678/getting-attribute-value-of-an-xml-document-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attributes doesn't have `InnerText`.You have to use the `Attributes` collection instead.

```
string adUrl = Doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id=\"offers_table\"]/tbody/tr["+i+ "]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/h3/a")
                               .Attributes["href"].Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the XDocument class?

```
private string GetUrl(string filename)
{
    var doc = XDocument.Load(filename)
    foreach (var h3Element in doc.Elements("h3").Where(e => e.Attribute("class"))
    {
        var classAtt = h3Element.Attribute("class");
        if (classAtt == "x-large lheight20 margintop5")
        {
            h3Element.Element("a").Attribute("href").value;
        }
    }
}
```

The code is not tested so use with caution.

Comment: Html are not as well formatted as xml. That is why we have libraries like html agility pack which can handle malformmatted  html very well.

Comment: Yes I know, but I was just answering based on the example provided.