# Save all nodes attributes XML

Tags: c#, xml, treenode

I have written a code that reads an `XMl` file and then construct a tree view of `XML` file using the nodes name. I would like to know how could I have attributes instead of the components(nodes) name?

For example, in the following `XML` file instead of `action`(s) I would like to print in the tree view `copy` or `paste`, etc, except for the first two parent nodes (`Report` and `test`).

`XML` file:

```
<Report version="2.1" xmlns="http://www.froglogic.com/XML2">
<test name="Example">
    <action name="delet">
        this is delet
    </action>
    <action name="copy">
        this is copy
    </action>
    <action name="paste">
        this is paste
    </action>
    <action name="manipulate">
        this is manipulate
    </action>
    <action name="copy">
        this is copy
    </action>
    <action name="paste">
        this is paste
    </action>
    <action name="manipulate">
        this is manipulate
    </action>
    <action name="change">
        this is change
    </action>
</test>
</Report>
```

and the `C#` code:

```
private void File2_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(File2Path.Text);

            treeView2.Nodes.Clear();
            treeView2.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(doc.DocumentElement.Name));
            TreeNode tNode = new TreeNode();
            tNode = treeView2.Nodes[0];

            AddNode(doc.DocumentElement, tNode);
            treeView2.ExpandAll();
            treeView2.CheckBoxes = true;
        }
        catch (XmlException xmlEx)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(xmlEx.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

**Update**

```
private void AddNode(XmlNode inXmlNode, TreeNode inTreeNode)
    {
        XmlNode xNode;
        TreeNode tNode;
        XmlNodeList nodeList;
        int i;

        if (inXmlNode.HasChildNodes)
        {
            nodeList = inXmlNode.ChildNodes;
            for (i = 0; i <= nodeList.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                xNode = inXmlNode.ChildNodes[i];
                inTreeNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(xNode.Name));
                tNode = inTreeNode.Nodes[i];
                AddNode(xNode, tNode);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            inTreeNode.Text = (inXmlNode.OuterXml).Trim();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting attribute value of an XML Document using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750678/getting-attribute-value-of-an-xml-document-using-c-sharp)

Comment: But What I need to have is the first two parrents name and then for the rest shows in the tree view attributes.

Comment: Show us the code of the method `AddNode` you call and we can help changing it.

Comment: @MartinHonnen please see the update.

Comment: You can not have two attributes with the same name manipulate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
            xNode = inXmlNode.ChildNodes[i];
            inTreeNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(xNode.Name));
```

to

```
            xNode = inXmlNode.ChildNodes[i];
            TreeNode childTreeNode;
            if (xNode.LocalName == "action" && xNode.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
              childTreeNode = new TreeNode(xNode.Attributes["name"].Value);
            }
            else
            {
              childTreeNode = new TreeNode(xNode.Name);
            }

            inTreeNode.Nodes.Add(childTreeNode);
```

You might want to add further checks on `NodeType` and `LocalName`, depending on the complexity of your XML input and the possible nodes that can be contained in the XML input.

Comment: I have changed `Getattributes("name")` to `Attributes["name"].Value`. Becaue there was an error.

Comment: @Saber, yes, sorry about that, `GetAttribute` is a method on `XmlElement` so I would have needed to cast first to an element. I have edited the sample, if your problem is now solved then you can accept the answer.