# How to get attributes from XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I am getting output xml format in that can able to access appointment-nbr, but I am not able to eqid. How can I get slot-start,slot-end,eqid.

```
 > <appointment-nbr>494</appointment-nbr> <slot
 > slot-start="2018-07-16T12:31:00" slot-end="2018-07-16T13:00:00" />
 > <appointment requires-xray="false" /> <container eqid="ASWU2705080" />
```

This is my code:

```
foreach (XmlNode node in appointmentsresponce){
XmlElement flightEle = (XmlElement)node;
XmlNodeList appointmentnbr = flightEle.GetElementsByTagName("appointment-nbr");
XmlNodeList containerNodeList = flightEle.GetElementsByTagName("container");
}
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question and post the a valid XML string?

Comment: Post the original xml if you want to be helped and type something understandable

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750678/getting-attribute-value-of-an-xml-document-using-c-sharp and this also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acwfyhc7(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try (I'm guessing a bit since you didn't post the full data):

```
foreach (XElement level1Element in XElement.Load(@"your_file.xml").Elements("appointment-nbr"))
{
    foreach (XElement level2Element in level1Element.Elements("slot"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(level1Element.Attribute("slot-start").Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: XmlDocument responceXml = new XmlDocument();
responceXml.LoadXml(soapResult);
 XmlNodeList appointmentsresponce = responceXml.GetElementsByTagName("basicInvokeResponse");
 foreach (XmlNode node in appointmentsresponce[0]) {
 XmlDocument responceXml2 = new XmlDocument();
 string samplexmlfile = Convert.ToString(node.InnerText);
 responceXml2.LoadXml(samplexmlfile);
 XmlNodeList appointmentsresponce2 = responceXml2.GetElementsByTagName("create-appointment-response");
  foreach (XmlNode node2 in appointmentsresponce2)
 {
 XmlElement flightEle = (XmlElement)node2;  }

Comment: Please check above my exact code,for that code how can i access data

Comment: Can you show the a xml file example that you are working with? From the code I can see elements such as "create-appointment-response" that aren't visible on the question

Answer (score 0):

Simple call `GetAttribute("AttributeName")` on your `XmlElement`

So:

```
var slotXml = appointmentsresponce.SelectSingleNode("//slot")
var startAttr = slotXml.GetAttribute("slot-start")
var endAttr = slotXml.GetAttribute("slot-end")

var containerXml = appointmentsresponce.SelectSingleNode("//container ")
var eqidAttr = containerXml .GetAttribute("eqid")
```